# Why is my reputation down to 1 at Super User?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday [my reputation](https://superuser.com/users/10483?tab=reputationhistory) was 76. But today it's only 1. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 5):

This post:

[Is there a difference between AMD and Intel processors?](https://superuser.com/questions/59740/is-there-a-difference-between-amd-and-intel-processors/59811#59811)

was marked as offensive. Seems a bit extreme to me, so I removed that from your vote table for now and recalculated.

Comment: (Just for those who, like me, click that link without the required reputation: that specific answer is not visible for most of us. So, it's *not* about the question itself that shows when clicking that link.)

Comment: There are times when I really miss that ♦ when visiting SU/SF.

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to see more when clicking that little envelope next to your name. (Only you can [see that](https://superuser.com/users/recent/10483?tab=reputation); we cannot.)

(And as this question will be moved to [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) some time later, you can register there to prepare for that, and then [associate your accounts](https://superuser.com/users/10483?tab=accounts).)

Answer (score 2):

Sudden drops like this can be caused by posts being marked offensive (you suddenly lose 100 points).

Comment: Aha, one learns something every day! Didn't know that. I guess this shows when clicking that little envelope?

Comment: I don't think it does. But it should, as should every rep-affecting event.